# Mysql, Load Data Infile, only particular lines

Tags: mysql, text-files

I'm struggling to add data from a text file into a mysql database. In my text file I have  dozens of lines from which I want to extract just specific ones (which are the ones with a similar structure as the table structure).

Table structure:

```
Name
Surname
Email
City
ZIP
```

Text File:

```
_field1 >>> blah 
otherfield >>> blah
Name >>> John
anotherfield >>> blah
Email >>> john@doe.com
City >>> Portland
ZIP >>> 90210
yetanotherfield >>> foo
```

Comment: Is the order in which fields appear within the file predictable?

Comment: load data infile '/tmp/textfile.txt' into table tablename.test fields terminated by '>>>' lines terminated by '\n';

Answer (score 0):

It's probably best to parse the file in some other language and then invoke `INSERT` from there, but since the order of fields within the file is predictable, you *could* go via user variables with something like:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE '/path/to/file.txt' INTO TABLE my_table
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\n' LINES TERMINATED BY 0x1e
    (@dummy, @dummy, @name, @dummy, @email, @city, @zip, @dummy)
SET Name  = SUBSTRING(@name,  LOCATE(' >>> ', @name ) + 5),
    Email = SUBSTRING(@email, LOCATE(' >>> ', @email) + 5),
    City  = SUBSTRING(@city,  LOCATE(' >>> ', @city ) + 5),
    ZIP   = SUBSTRING(@zip,   LOCATE(' >>> ', @zip  ) + 5);
```